# OpenGL application exited with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: c++, cmake, glfw, glew, assimp

I'm trying to write simple OpenGL application, but I bumped into this strange problem. When I tries launch my app, it crashes with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135). I downloaded and unpacked all the libraries I needed into the `win` folder. Here my CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_subdirectory(win/glfw)
add_subdirectory(win/assimp)
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)
add_subdirectory(win/glew/build/cmake)
include_directories(win/glew/include)
include_directories(win/glfw/include)
include_directories("win/glm")
include_directories("win/assimp/include")
link_libraries(assimp glew glfw opengl32 pthread)

add_executable(test ...)
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using CLion and Windows 10

Comment: Did you write any code in addition to the downloaded libs?

Comment: Are all dependencies (library DLL files) in the executable directory after compilation?

Comment: FYI, error code `0xC0000135` is [Unable to Find Component](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp/stop-error-c0000135/69608ed5-586c-40d1-816c-30db43a1f8f7).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `glew` I should use `glew_s` target. So, `link_libraries(assimp glew_s glfw opengl32 pthread)` solved my problem

Comment: Can you please elaborate and explain for better understanding what is the difference?